# Angular bindings ignored in angular-chart canvas

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart, chart.js2

I'm trying to work with [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) via [angular-chart.js](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js) integration.  When I omit angular declaratives, it works.  When I add angular declaratives, the data-binding doesn't occur.

```
<!-- This works -->
<canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut" chart-data="[50,100]" chart-labels="['TEXT','MINUTES']" </canvas>
<p>Text: {{$ctrl.myText}} {{$ctrl.myMinutes}}</p>

<!--  This does not work -->
<canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut" chart-data="[{{$ctrl.myText}},{{$ctrl.myMinutes}}]" chart-labels="['TEXT','MINUTES']" </canvas>
```

Why do the model-bindings work when they are within regular markup, but fail when used as the content of an attribute?

p.s. in the markup shown above, I removed the following canvas attribute:

```
chart-options="{cutoutPercentage:0, segmentStrokeWidth:50,tooltips:false}"
```

It was making my sample hard to read, and isn't pertinent to this question.

Comment: Have you tried without the double curly braces in the attribute content?

Comment: @garethb I had not tried that until now.  It worked!  This was my answer.